# How do I use layered pane?

Tags: java

I wanted to have my backround image and on top of it I wanted to have image that the user can click on and do stuff.

How do I use it properly?

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {          
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            p.setVisible(false);
            p2.setVisible(false);
            JLayeredPane lp2=new JLayeredPane();
            JLayeredPane lp=new JLayeredPane();
            ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("800x800.jpg"));
            JLabel lbl=new JLabel(image);
            ImageIcon image2=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("imageYEA.jpg"));
            JLabel lbl2=new JLabel(image2);
            lp2.add(lbl2);
            lp.add(lbl);
            add(lp2);
            add(lp);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I think you don't need 2 layered panes. You make one and then on that pane you draw 2 pictures. They are overlapping with a predefined offset. You can see how it's done in the official Oracle tutorial here: [LayeredPaneDemo.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/LayeredPaneDemoProject/src/components/LayeredPaneDemo.java). If you want to make something with the upper picture I guess a normal event handler will do the job for you.